# Django S3Direct renaming files

Tags: python, django, amazon-s3

I'm using S3Direct to upload to AWS S3, and it's working fine. However when I upload a different file of the same name it overwrites. I turned versions on and now it stores the file with a different url on the server but the reference URL in Django is the same, so I end up with two of the last uploaded video.

I attempted to add this to the javascript, which did nothing.

```
var getUploadURL = function(e) {
    var el       = e.target.parentElement,
        file     = el.querySelector('.file-input').files[0],
        dest     = el.querySelector('.file-dest').value,
        url      = el.getAttribute('data-policy-url'),
        form     = new FormData(),
        headers  = {'X-CSRFToken': getCookie('csrftoken')}

    /* These vars were added by me */
    var currentdate = new Date($.now());
        var datetime = currentdate.getDate() + "/"
            + (currentdate.getMonth()+1)  + "/" 
            + currentdate.getFullYear() + " @ "  
            + currentdate.getHours() + ":"  
            + currentdate.getMinutes() + ":" 
            + currentdate.getSeconds();

    form.append('type', file.type)
    form.append('ext', file.datetime)/* Added by me */
    form.append('name', file.name) 
    form.append('dest', dest)
```

And this in the view:

```
def get_upload_params(request):
    /* The first two lines were already there */
    content_type = request.POST['type']
    filename = request.POST['name']
    print "Filename before time added: ", filename
    ext = os.path.splitext(filename)[1]
    name = os.path.splitext(filename)[0]

    time_now = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d+%H:%M:%S")
    filename = name + time_now + ext
    print "Filename after time added: ", filename
```

This returned what I expected in the terminal, however the filename passed into S3 was the same as the original, it just created another version. And the url sent to the database was the url for the original filename and original version on S3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked it out. At the bottom of the view in the else of the `get_upload_params()`

```
    time_now = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H-%M-%S")
    key = '%s/${filename}%s' % (key, time_now)
```

NB: The time can't have colons (' : ') in the url, because S3 encodes them meaning the url stored in the db has colons, and the actual url does not, so you can't reference it.